# How works the ePWM block?

Tags: embedded, simulink

I know it's a basic question but I want to understand how works the ePWM block from simulink ? On Matlab documentation I find just the configuration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ePWM block is part of the [Embedded Coder Support Package for Texas Instruments C2000 Processors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/texasinstrumentsc2000/index.html) for Simulink. You'll first have to install this support package in Simulink. See [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/texasinstrumentsc2000/ug/install-support-for-c2000-processors.html) for that.

This block is for using the ePWM module (enhanced PWM module) in the compatible Texas Instruments microcontrollers. PWM module is a common module found in most MCUs for generating PWM signals. The [MathWorks page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/texasinstrumentsc2000/ug/c280xc2802xc2803xc2805xc2806xc2833xc2834xf28m3xf2807xf2837xdf2837xsepwm.html) shows the following families of TI microcontrollers supporting this feature:

C280x
C2802x
C2803x
C2805x
C2806x
C2833x
C2834x
F28M3x
F2807x
F2837xD
F2837xS

If you haven't deployed Simulink models to development boards before, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxYTLbYfBP0) will help you deploying Simulink models to TI C2000 series microcontrollers.

You will find more information on how it works in the ePWM module datasheets provided by Texas Instruments. A good starting point can be this: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru791f/spru791f.pdf